# SQL aggregation using join

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have 2 tables with Naam as primary key, the one table contains information on Naam (lumchartcentrumuser) and the other table contains information on presentations held by naam (lumchartecentrumonderwijs).

I want to use a bit more complex aggregation which counts the number of presentations grouped by Naam, using a where however i keep on getting errrors. Does anybody see what i am doing wrong :

```
SELECT lumchartcentrumuser.Naam,
       COUNT(lumchartecentrumonderwijs.ID) AS Getal
FROM lumchartecentrumonderwijs
WHERE lumchartcentrumuser.Type <> 3
 AND lumchartecentrumonderwijs.Categorie <> "
LEFT JOIN lumchartcentrumuser ON
lumchartecentrumonderwijs.Naam=lumchartcentrumuser.Naam 
GROUP BY Naam
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: a fatal syntax error

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` should be placed right after `FROM`.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is wrong. It should be like `SELECT..FROM...JOIN...WHERE...GROUP BY`

```
SELECT lumchartcentrumuser.Naam, COUNT(lumchartecentrumonderwijs.ID) AS Getal
FROM lumchartecentrumonderwijs 
LEFT JOIN lumchartcentrumuser 
ON lumchartecentrumonderwijs.Naam=lumchartcentrumuser.Naam 
WHERE lumchartcentrumuser.Type <> 3 AND 
      lumchartecentrumonderwijs.Categorie <> '' 
GROUP BY Naam
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your `WHERE` statements below the `JOIN` statements. Something like this

```sql
SELECT lumchartcentrumuser.Naam, COUNT(lumchartecentrumonderwijs.ID) AS Getal
FROM lumchartecentrumonderwijs 
LEFT JOIN lumchartcentrumuser 
ON lumchartecentrumonderwijs.Naam = lumchartcentrumuser.Naam
WHERE lumchartcentrumuser.Type <> 3 AND lumchartecentrumonderwijs.Categorie <> ""
GROUP BY Naam
```

Also make sure you close your quotation marks (fixed above).